# Second Header fading in or fading out depending of scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, header, fading

Im coding a website and I want to have 2 headers..one showing when user is on top of the page and second one when you scroll. I tried to do that with `jquery` and it works like its supposed to do(on top of the page is "top", when I scroll down "top2"), but when I scroll back to the top, the second one(that's supposed to fade out) filckers/blinks one time then fades out.

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollval = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollval >= 50) {
            $("#top").fadeOut('slow');
            $("#top2").fadeIn('slow');
       }
       if (scrollval <= 10) {
           $("#top").fadeIn('slow');
           $("#top2").fadeOut('slow');
       }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="top">....</div>
<div id="top2>...</div>
```

CSS

```
#top {
    background:red;
    width:100%; 
    height: 50px; 
} 
#top2 {
    display: none; 
    position:fixed; 
    top:0; 
    left: 0; 
    background:black; 
    width:100%; 
    height: 50px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
}
```

Comment: and what about HTML and CSS code ?

Comment: in HTML, 2 divs
    <div id="top">....</div>
and
    <div id="top2>...</div>

Comment: and in css
    
   #top {
       background:red;
       width:100%;
       height: 50px;
   }
   #top2 {
    display: none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    background:black;
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin:0 auto; 
    }

Comment: has #top2 completly diffrent content or just different styling ?

Comment: #top2 is completly different content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to .fadeOut('slow') and .fadeIn('slow');..the code below will fix the issue

html

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="top2"></div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollval = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollval >= 50) {
            $("#top").css("opacity", 0);
            $("#top2").css("opacity", 1);
        }
        if (scrollval <= 10) {
            $("#top").css("opacity", 1);
            $("#top2").css("opacity", 0);
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#top {
    background:red;
    width:100%; 
    height: 50px; 
} 
#top2 {
    opacity: 0;
    position:fixed; 
    top:0; 
    left: 0; 
    background:blue; 
    width:100%; 
    height: 50px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: yes and its working...Anything missing ?...since the event is happening on scroll, you can add some test contents below the #top and #top2

Comment: This works, thank you!
But, why it wasn't woking with fadeIn and fadeOut?
And can I make this transition with ".css('opacity')" smoother?

Comment: since we are using fadeIn and fadeOut..it will be making the content display none and block.While make it display block the height will change and result in change of scroll value. you can console log scroll value and see it..for making it smooth i added a transition in CSS and i updated the code...if it helps, upvote for it...thanks !